# mysqldump export to delimited-text mixed data (blob and text) and restore

Tags: mysql

I am using this code bellow to export all tables from database , not all in one file but in one folder foreach table one .sql file with table structure and one .txt file with delimited-text data

```
mysqldump -uroot -pmy_pass --tab=/path/to/export my_database --fields-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=,
```

But I have certain tables that contains also blob data (mixed columns some blob some text)

I have added **--hex-blob** parameter believing that they will be exported in hexadecimal, but this not ocurred (when I take a look to the delimited-text file that is some like unicode -- Ithink that is bynary -> "o2¼ë2æã‡_g9yùaÿÿQ§M!)

For restoring I use this (with PHP mysqli)

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$my_file' 
IGNORE INTO TABLE $my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

That turn into error when I try to import

> Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '"o2'

I have tried also **--default-character-set=binary** (on mysqldump export)
and **mysqli_set_charset( $my_conn , "binary " );** on restoring,
but same error.

Source and destination database have utf8mb4 charset

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are making it more difficult in yourself by using the `--tab` option, when a simple, ordinary, default behavior mysqldump file... just works?

Comment: The only reason was to have separate tables backup with a single command. (It was too beautiful to be true, but it is not) But since I have seen that this way there is no way to solve it, I will make a script in php to manage all databases with their folders-tables with **mysqldump db_name table_name > table_name.sql** ... So you're right